# Truncating the data-frame column values in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

df is the dataframe, and

df.select($"createdon").show

output is:

```
|           createdon|
+--------------------+
|2017-05-11 15:29:...|
|2017-05-11 15:29:...|
|2017-05-11 11:02:...|
|2017-05-11 11:02:...|
|2017-05-11 15:29:...|
```

I need the createdon value to be just the date instead of whole timestamp. How to have the new dataframe containing createdon's value to be just the date instead of whole timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map transformation (assuming, that selected values are of the String type)

`df.select($"createdon").map(_.getAs[String]("createdon").substring(0, 11)).show()`

Answer (score 1):

`to_date` function should do it:

```
df.withColumn("createdon", to_date($"createdon")).show
+----------+
| createdon|
+----------+
|2017-05-11|
+----------+
```